# Naming convention rules: Id in plural

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, naming

I have a question about C# naming convention rules.

I know that you write ex. `CustomerId`.

But what if it the property is a `List` of `CustomerId`'s?

Should I write `CustomerIds` or `CustomerIdS`?

Comment: Definitely not the later. That just looks silly.

Comment: In my experience, you don't make plural names.  I agree with Selman.  "CustomerIdList" would be most appropriate.

Comment: @MattBurland You could always expand it: `CustomerIdentifiers` ;)

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx) describes using pascal casing for member names. There is no specific guideline on plurals as far as I can see, but I would suggest `CustomerIds` since it feels more natural to me.

Also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) the question between `ID` and `Id` is answered: use `Id`.

Comment: I thought two letter acronyms should both be upper case (e.g. `CustomerIDs`). Is this not the case?

Comment: @Rotem: No. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @Rotem "Id" is an abbreviation, not an acronym.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks, I didn't see they explicitly give `Id` as an example.

Comment: @Rotem: It isn't `ID` as in the sample. And `id` should be camel-cased, so `Id`. `id` on itself should stay `id`.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I also think that IdS looks bad. But agree that Ids looks the "best". But think that CustomerIdList is a great version

Comment: @JVJ: No problem. Glad it was helpful. Since you are new, please don't forget to accept the answer you liked best.